# Один обработчик для двух кнопок в котлине

Tags: android, kotlin

Как это сделать на котлине

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   // по id определеяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.btnOk:
     // кнопка ОК
     tvOut.setText("Нажата кнопка ОК");
     break;
   case R.id.btnCancel:
     // кнопка Cancel
     tvOut.setText("Нажата кнопка Cancel");
     break;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В котлине это делается так

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    // по id определеяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
    when(v.id) { 
       // кнопка ОК
       R.id.btnOk -> tvOut.text = "Нажата кнопка ОК"
       // кнопка Cancel
       R.id.btnCancel -> tvOut.text = "Нажата кнопка Cancel"
    }
}
```